# Testing .Net Core Library with xUnit

Tags: .net-core, xunit, xunit.net, project.json

I am creating a `.Net Core Library` that can be consumed by `ASP.NET Core` Application. By default Visual Studio create project.json as below

```
{
  "dependencies": {

    "NETStandard.Library": "1.6.0"
  },
  "frameworks": {
    "netstandard1.6": {
      "imports": "dnxcore50"
    }
  },
  "version": "1.0.0-*"
}
```

I think its recommended to use `netstandard1.x` for libraries that will be consumed by other applications. I am going to remove `"imports": "dnxcore50"` because that was for older .NET Core preview versions (Before .NET Core 1.0 RTM and .NET Core RC2 were released)

Now I wanted to unit test this library using `xunit` so followed the article [Getting started with xUnit.net (.NET Core / ASP.NET Core)](http://xunit.github.io/docs/getting-started-dotnet-core.html) 
However xunit suggest to mark the library as .Net Core Application

> You may have noticed that part of what we did here was mark your class
>   library as a .NET Core Application (the netcoreapp1.0 framework). When
>   using .NET CLI for testing, unit test projects are actually an
>   application*, not a class library. If you forget to make this change,
>   the compiler will tell you that dotnet-test-xunit is not compatible
>   with your class library project. We tell Visual Studio to generate a
>   class library, though, because it most closely matches our desired
>   project structure.
>
> - The application's Main function is provided by the xUnit.net runner, not by you.

So I have updated the project.josn as suggested and I was able to run the unit test. However I have questions:

1> Is it recommended to change the target framework of the .Net Core library from `netstandard1.6` to `netcoreapp1.0` when that library can be consumed by other applications?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You'll have one project (and project.json) dedicated to your test project.

You need to mark the Test project as a .NET Core application since it will in fact be executed. 
No need to change the target project which is your Library to Core App.

Here you can see the [project.json for a test project](https://github.com/bruno-garcia/SharpSyslogServer/blob/master/SharpSyslogServer.Tests/project.json)

And here the [library project](https://github.com/bruno-garcia/SharpSyslogServer/blob/master/SharpSyslogServer/project.json)